# Foundation 5 Dropdowns - have link click through AND hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation 5 and have implemented a side bar "fly out" categories / sub categories menu using the [Dropdowns feature](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/dropdown.html).

This all works as expected however I need the top level category link to click through as well as hover to show the sub categories.  Does anyone know how I would achieve this?

```
<ul class="side-nav nav-bar vertical">  
<li>
<a id="showDropdown" href="http://www.google.com" data-options="is_hover:true;align:right;" data-dropdown="drop_[CategoryID]" >[CategoryName]</a>
<ul id="drop_[CategoryID]" class="small f-dropdown" data-dropdown-content>
<li> <a href="http://www.google.com">[CategoryName]</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I imagine the dropdown feature works in the same way as the top bar and this also does not seem to support having a top level link that clicks through as well as a hover.  Does anyone know why this is as this is pretty standard isn't it?

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the idea is that on mobile devices it's **really** quite annoying if you tap a dropdown menu then the page buggers off somewhere else before you can select a sub-option, so it's easier to just not listen for clicks on the parent link.

If you want to re-add the functionality you can do something simple enough such as [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bsbnnaq2/)*:

```
<a data-follow-click id="showDropdown" href="http://www.google.com" data-options="is_hover:true;align:right;" data-dropdown="drop_7">[CategoryName]</a>

$(function() {
    $('[data-follow-click]').on('click', function() {
        location.href = this.href;
    });
});
```

Obviously this is a very rough example and doesn't fire any more complicated handlers, it just lets `href` go through, but that works for the OP example.

***Note:** the fiddle doesn't follow links to Google - check the console to see when a request is or isn't going through :-)